# Bind variables to ActiveRecord select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In ActiveRecord, how can I bind prepared statement variables in a `select`? For example:

```
Group.select('(EXTRACT(epoch FROM created_at) / $1)::int AS interval')
```

The $1 parameter is calculated from the user input so I was tempted to just concatenate strings, but I guess it's no ideal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think, you may use the [string interpolation](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics) in this case

Comment: You can't use `select` like this. See the documentation page: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

Comment: I see... I guess I'll use `connection.select_all` and pass the whole SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a go around, only you must define a `method` in `model` to do calculations as you need:

```
def self.interval_divided_by dividend
  Group.select('(EXTRACT(epoch FROM created_at))::int AS interval').interval / dividend
end
```

Then use it:

```
Group.interval_divided_by 4
```